# Localizar diretório usando coringas

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Como localizar uma pasta como se fosse um arquivo?

Por exemplo, o código para localizar o arquivo `TESTE.TXT` é:

```
b = dir("c:\minhapasta\t*.*xt")
msgbox b
```

Mas para pastas o asterisco não funciona. Qual alternativa temos?

Answer (score 1):

Pode<sup>(*)</sup> usar o método `GetDirectories()` da classe *Directory* para obter o caminho dos diretórios que se encontram no diretório `c:\minhapasta\` e que correspondam ao padrão de pesquisa `t*`

```
Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\minhapasta\", "t*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Se quiser que a pesquisa se estenda a sub-diretórios altere o segundo parâmetro para `SearchOption.AllDirectories`.

Poderá depois utilizar um *For Each* para percorrer cada um desses diretórios e obter os caminhos aos `*.txt`

(*) <sub>Em VB, julgo que em VBA seja igual.</sub>
<sub>Fonte: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)</sub>

Comment: Muito obrigado Ramaral. deu certo.